# Building Results From Advanced Search Form

Tags: search

I'm building an advanced search form and having some difficulty with getting the results. The form inputs include price and year ranges. For example, search for used cars from $10,000 to $20,000.

The search is working, here's my results page code:

```
{% set manufacturer = craft.request.getParam('manufacturer') %}
{% set model = craft.request.getParam('model') %}
{% set bodyStyle = craft.request.getParam('bodyStyle') %}

{% set minPrice = craft.request.getParam('minPrice') %}
{% set maxPrice = craft.request.getParam('maxPrice') %}

{% set startYear = craft.request.getParam('startYear') %}
{% set endYear = craft.request.getParam('endYear') %}

{% set results = craft.entries.section('usedCars').type('entry').search().manufacturer(manufacturer).model(model).bodyStyle(bodyStyle) %}
```

This is how i'm showing the price range.

```
{% if minPrice|length and maxPrice|length %}
{% for entry in results if entry.price <= maxPrice and entry.price >= minPrice %}

{% if minPrice is empty and maxPrice|length %}
{% for entry in results if entry.price <= maxPrice %}

and so on etc...
```

The trouble with this method is it's all based on a whole stack of "IF" statements and when I start to think about adding the year ranges too, my head starts to hurt. Is there an easier way to achieve the same thing?

I'd appreciate any nod in a general direction, or help simplifying my code down...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set multiple conditions on a single ElementCriteriaModel parameter. Pass it either a comma-separated list as a string or an array of conditions.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.id('84, 62, < 7, 29') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.id([84, 62, < 7, 29]) %}
```

In this example, each entry with any of these IDs is returned (→ `or` logic).
To return only those entries that match all criteria of your list (→ `and` logic), set the first value to `and`:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.id('and, > 100, < 200, not 110') %}
```

In your case I'd set the "year" and "price" parameters as an array and combine it with all other `craft.entries` parameters using the object syntax like so:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({

    section: 'usedCars',
    type: 'entry',
    manufacturer: manufacturer,
    model: model,
    bodyStyle: bodyStyle,
    price: [
        'and',
        '>= ' ~ minPrice,
        '<= ' ~ maxPrice,
    ],
    year: [
        'and',
        '>= ' ~ startYear,
        '<= ' ~ endYear,
    ],

}) %}
```

Make sure that your "year" and "price" variables are not empty by setting default values:

```
{% set startYear = craft.request.getParam('startYear') %}
{% set startYear = startYear is not empty ? startYear : '1900' %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlcs! Works perfectly, really appreciate it. I hadn't realised you could set multiple conditions on a single ElementCriteriaModel parameter. Some great learnings in your answer.

Comment: How can we make params on condition llike if data entered by user only than filter .https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30188/craftcms-3-search-form-with-filters

Answer (score 3):

If statements should be fine. What you're building is a query to find things later. So you could easily start with the query:

```
{% set query = craft.entries.section('usedCars').type('entry') %}
```

Then add parameters as they exist:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('manufacturer') %}
    {% set query = query.manufacturer(craft.request.getParam('manufacturer')) %}
{% endif %}
```

Also, I don't see an actual search query (like from a search box). If you're just searching based on predefined parameters, you don't need to add `search()`. That's mainly for full text searching.

When you're all set, you can then check for results:

```
{% if query.total() %}
```

And display them if there's any:

```
{% for car in query %}
    {{ car.title }}
{% endfor %}
```